# paste two files according to concordance between columns

Tags: shell, join, awk, paste, cut

I would need some help about this:

I have file1:

```
ID
100
102
103
104
108
109
112
.
.
.
```

And file2:

```
ID    []    p1    p2
100    2.5    3.0    2.0
101    2.0    4.0    3.0
102    2.6    4.0    2.5
103    2.3    2.0    NA
104    2.3    2.0    2.0
105    3.5    2.8    2.0
106    1.7    NA    3.2
107    5.0    4.0    4.0
108    3.2    2.0    4.0
109    2.9    1.0    1.5
110    5.0    NA    NA
111    2.9    4.0    4.0
112    3.1    2.5    2.0
.
.
.
```

I would like to paste both files in file3 looking like:

```
ID    []    p1    p2
100    2.5    3.0    2.0
102    2.6    4.0    2.5
103    2.3    2.0    NA
104    2.3    2.0    2.0
108    3.2    2.0    4.0
109    2.9    1.0    1.5
112    3.1    2.5    2.0
.
.
.
```

Basically, pasting data in fields 2,3,4 from file2 to file1, considering concordancies in field1 in both file1 and file2.

I've tried some awk commands with NR == NFR but I just get the output with the content of file1 followed by content of file2...

Any help? Unix commands with cut and paste are also welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed use `awk` for that:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1} NR>FNR && a[$1]' file1 file2
```

`NR==FNR{a[$1]=1}` The `a` array filled with the content of file1.

`NR>FNR && a[$1]` is printing the line of file2 if the array contains the ID (aka `$1`).

Comment: you should use `$1 in a` to check, `a[$1]` will create that element with null string(similarly, `NR==FNR{a[$1]}` is enough)... see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html

Answer (score 3):

If you like to use join, you can simply do:

```
join file file2
```

or , if input is tab separated and you use bash:

```
join -t $'\t' file1 file2
```

Comment: The op has not confirmed that the input is tab delimited, so your first solution would work like a charm.

Comment: As posted *file2* has multiple spaces, not tabs, but this works: `join -t $'\t' file1 <(tr -s ' ' '\t' < file2)`, or (no *bash*isms) `join file[12] | column -t`.

Comment: I was rather suprised by the simplivcity of the join approach. Then I realised that it was stripping spaces compared to the expected output from the question. That made me assume that the original file had probably tabs that were lost when creating the question and I added the remark about the tabs, especially because I cant just use `\t`. 
If the file has really multiple spaces and not one space or a tab, the simple join based approach has the flaw that it will join the multiple spaces into a single delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

A more idiomatic `awk` solution would be :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{id[$1];next}$1 in id' file1 file2 >file3
```

**Output**

```
ID    []    p1    p2
100    2.5    3.0    2.0
102    2.6    4.0    2.5
103    2.3    2.0    NA
104    2.3    2.0    2.0
108    3.2    2.0    4.0
109    2.9    1.0    1.5
112    3.1    2.5    2.0
```

---

**References:**

1. awk [[ referring to an array element ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html).
2. awk [[ next statement ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html#Next-Statement).