# how to extract rows from file1 based on matching information of its/file1 (only)first column with file2 in linux?

Tags: linux

I  have two files that look like this:

```
file 1:
HO840F3000336240 HOUSAM129901651 HOUSAF132871174 F 20060607 Yes
HO840F3000336251 HOUSAM129800008 HOUSAF135774690 F 20060718 Yes
HO840F3000336254 HOUSAM129901651 HOUSAF135357862 F 20060724 Yes
HO840F3000487279 HOUSAM131520543 HOUSAF135761935 F 20061226 Yes
HOUSAM55967108 HOUSAM53557280 HOUSAF53557285 M 20091129 Yes
HOUSAF55969445 HOUSAM55967108 HOUSAF53579684 F 20120103 Yes

file 2:
HO840F3000336251
HO840F3000487279
HOUSAF135761935
HOUSAM55967108
```

What I would like to do is to extract those rows from File 1 where  first column is common with the first column in  File 2. So, based on this example, the output should be :

```
file3:

HO840F3000336251 HOUSAM129800008 HOUSAF135774690 F 20060718 Yes
HO840F3000487279 HOUSAM131520543 HOUSAF135761935 F 20061226 Yes
HOUSAM55967108 HOUSAM53557280 HOUSAF53557285 M 20091129 Yes
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Probably a question best suited for superuser.com or serverfault.com, but there we go: `for line in \`cat file2\`; {  grep $line file1; } > file3`

Comment: Good suggestion by Paulo, but the ideal site for this type of question is http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38400436/4082052) works perfectly... this question should be marked as duplicate I feel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [paste two files according to concordance between columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397331/paste-two-files-according-to-concordance-between-columns)

Comment: Paulo Scardine this does not give the correct answer. because grep not only compare first column of file1 with first column of file2 and takes those commons, but it also compares the other columns of file1 with the first column in file2. I need a script to take just those that are in common in first columns file1 with first columns of file2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using join command instead of grep.

after sorting both files based on first column:

```
join File1 file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

This command will create file3 with the desired output. Tested and works:

`cat file1 | grep -f file2 > file3`

Output:

```
HO840F3000336251 HOUSAM129800008 HOUSAF135774690 F 20060718 Yes
HO840F3000487279 HOUSAM131520543 HOUSAF135761935 F 20061226 Yes
```

It uses the `-f` switch in grep which takes a file name with one pattern per line. As per `man grep`:

```
    -f FILE, --file=FILE
Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, 
and therefore enter code here`matches nothing.  (-f is  specified by POSIX.)
```